# Facebook chat not working with empathy in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: empathy

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and been trying to connect to facebook chat using Empathy. But the connection is not getting successful, and it is showing **"Disconnected - network error"**.
The parameters I entered is the following:

Protocol:Jabber

Jabber ID:  someone.someone@chat.facebook.com (The facebook username being www.facebook.com/someone.someone)

Jabber Password: something (My facebook password)

Encryption required: TLS/SSL

Server: chat.facebook.com

Port: 5222

How to resolve the issue? Please Help.

Comment: are you sure yo ugave jabber the right paramethers? Take a look here.
http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tips-shortcuts/quick-tip-using-facebook-chat-with-messages-on-mac/

Comment: I am sure about the parameters. I have given the right username and password, no doubt about that. But still it's not working.

Comment: This is true. My Empathy connection in FB chat has had intermittent problems back two months ago when it previously hadn't had these.

Answer (score 1):

For the current period (now is August 2013), this seems to be a Facebook new feature compatibility problem. The following links below shows that not only Empathy suffers this "Network Error", but also all (most, probably) IM clients.

It seems that FB has recently [changed its authentication scheme](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/). I'm not sure if someone is working out there to address this change so that Empathy will soon be compatible with FB's X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL authentication mechanism.

The best thing to probably do now (if we are not developers) is to sit down, relax, and wait until we can thank those hard-working programmers in fixing this. (And I suppose that guys both client-side and server-side are now working out for this.)

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201413884891742
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152943143300125
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=658562000823930
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=529872150394426

Answer (score 1):

I solved somehow, putting in the edition of connection parameters my facebook user name
www.facebook.com/**TheUsernameIsHere**
The connection established and I could edit nick

(Protocol: Facebook)